# Selenium Chrome webdriver hangs occasionally c#

Tags: c#, selenium, google-chrome, freeze

I'm using selenium webdriver to handle Chrome browser for long running process, and some times it hangs on opening new url. This occurs randomly as I noticed, when the browser window is not active for long time. As soon as I activated the browser window, the browser resumes and loads the website. I'm using following options to initiate the driver.

```
 ChromeOptions opt = new ChromeOptions();
 opt.AddArguments(@"user-data-dir=./chromeprofile");
 opt.AddArguments(@"disable-infobars");
 opt.AddArguments(@"disable-notifications");
```

I guess the Chrome is pausing the browser until the user returns to the browser window. I just want to know is there any option to add here, to keep going the process even if the browser window goes inactive for long time. Can anyone point me in right direction to find a way to keep the browser working for long time without focus?

Comment: Which version of Chrome and ChromeDriver are you using? Is there a particular line of code this always seems to happen on?

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include all the code used to initialize ChromeDriver?

Comment: As far as I know - there is no such behavior like 'Chrome is pausing the browser until the user returns to the browser window' - OS processes doesn't work like that. The only situation that can ends with a Selenium timeout is when a page executes a long running, blocking JS code. As previous speakers said - could you provide more deatils?